# Calculating Percentage the best way alongside a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following query where I'm trying to calculate a percentage column, but it isn't calculating correctly with it showing 100 for each row which is clearly incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here? I've seen many examples of calculating percentages with many different ways and I'm wondering what would be the best approach here.

```
Select 
DrugName, 
Occurrences,  
(Occurrences / sum(Occurrences)) * 100 as Percentage
from
(
select 
D.DrugName,
count(*) as Occurrences
from
Visit V
Inner Join Drug D on 
V.DrugID = D.DrugID
where
StartDate >='01 Oct 2016' and
EndDate < '01 Jan 2017'
group by
D.DrugName
) a
group by
DrugName,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this uses window functions:

```
select D.DrugName,
       count(*) as Occurrences,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
from Visit V Inner Join
     Drug D 
     on V.DrugID = D.DrugID
where StartDate >= '2016-10-01' and
      EndDate < '2017-01-01'
group by D.DrugName;
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortnately that doesn't work either. It returns 0.024390243902 for every row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, changing 1.0 to 100.0 did the trick for me. As John suggested below.